# Stars and Bars with bounds but order matters

Tags: combinatorics

This question is related to [Stars and Bars with bounds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922819/stars-and-bars-with-bounds)

> I have what I thought is a fairly simple problem: Count non-negative
> integer solutions to the equation
>
> $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 23$$
>
> such that $0 \leq x_1 \leq 9$.

The accepted answer uses nCr such that order does not matter. But if order does matter can the  function be replaced from
\begin{align*}
[x^j](1+x)^n=\binom{n}{j}
\end{align*}
to then be

\begin{align*}
[x^j](1+x)^n=n^j
\end{align*}

Comment: $[x^j](1+x)^n=\binom{n}{j}$ is just an example of the $[x^j]$ notation, it's not actually related to the answer.

Comment: Okay I see, so how does \binom{k+4}{4}x^k translate if order matters?

Comment: What exactly do you mean in this context by *order matters*?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The "bin" order. The original treats 1+2+3+4+5 as a series such that their order doesnt matter. AKA 9+9+5+0+0 is that same as 0+0+5+9+9. What if I want to count these two possibilities as unique solutions?

Comment: You are mistaken. $9+9+5+0+0$ and $0+0+5+9+9$ are counted in the original as two different solutions.

Comment: @Coffee_Overflow: If one actually uses a combination of stars and bars and, to deal with the upper bound, inclusion-exclusion, order of the bins is automatically taken into account.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott ... as well as the generating functions.

Answer (score 0):

My confusion was with why the "Choose" function was used rather than the "Permute" function when order matters. According to @user by the nature of the stars and bars and by extension, generating function it takes the order of the bins into account despite using the choose function as a basis.

This offers the best example for how this happens: https://youtu.be/zjtxJSkjejc?t=308

Comment: As already pointed out in another comment the "Choose" function was used only as example to demonstrate what is the action of the coefficient extractor. It is absolutely hopeless trying to modify a method without its understanding.